# Adding 'default text' to Joomla's extension 'Simple Email Form'

Tags: joomla

I just want to add some 'default text' to the fields...
My efforts to edit the PHP have not worked at all !!

I'm guessing that the file to edit is the ' mod_simpleemailform.php '
I cant seem to find the "echo's" that spit out the form...

Am i on the right track...?

Thanks!!

Comment: well i can find the echo's, when i alter the loop it seems to have no effect on the html output...???

Comment: If you point me a link to where you found this module then I could give you a much more precise answer as to where your form is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my research this is not a module that comes installed with Joomla! I will answer your question when it comes to properly formated modules.

To find your form go into the folder for your module. In your case it should be `/modules/mod_simpleemailform`.

This is where the "System" for your module resides. You will find files such as:

`mod_simpleemailform.xml` This is a configuration file for the module.

`index.html` This prevents the listing of your module's folder contents.

`helper.php` This is where your module's functions and brains are located.

`mod_simpleemailform.php` This calls functions in your `helper.php` in order to get content and information. Once it has all of its data it will call a template file for the module located in `/tmpl` of your module's directory.

In here you will find:

`index.html` It does the same thing as the previous `index.html`

`default.php` This is your default template file for your module. This file will contain your form and HTML code that you see on screen.

The `default.php` is the file that you likely want to use. It is possible that your form is in an other file located in the `/tmpl` folder so you may have to pick around a little bit.

Usually your fields are not in an `echo` they are just place on the outside of php tags. You will likely want to add a `value` attribute and then add some text to it like so `<input type="text" name="myField" value="My Default Text" />`.

Even better still you could add parameters to the XML file so then you may echo a default text you entered in the back-end of Joomla!.

Comment: Thanks very much for you overview, extremely helpful !! ;)
I did manage to work it out and have the default text i wanted with the styles applied also that i wanted, its starting to look like a pretty good form now :P



You were spot on! I ended up going into the module/mod_simpleemailform folder and editing the mod_simpleemailform.php. I simple added some onfocus & onBlur javascript tag lines where the php echo's spit out the input fields. In the end it wasnt that hard, but it was kinda intimidating cause i had never used joomla b4 4 days ago. Thanks all for your input !! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just follow on Jonathan's answer, yes, you can find the brain of the module inside of `helper.php`and all that you need to achieve your goal: "add some 'default text' to the fields".

Inside the constructor function, you can find the following sentence, that save in `$l` the name of the current field (because it's inside a loop):

```
$l = trim($params->get($labelLabel));
```

you can just add a string with your desired default text (i.e. inside a variable: $myDefaultText):

```
$l = $myDefaultText . trim($params->get($labelLabel));
```